# How can I show empty bins on the plot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe df with `Gender`and `Results` columns

```
x <- df$Results
cuts <- cut(x, breaks = seq(min(x),max(x),(max(x)-min(x))/15) , include.lowest = TRUE, right = TRUE,dig.lab = 5)
df$cuts <- mgsub::mgsub(as.character(cuts),pattern =c("\\[","\\]","\\(","\\)",",") ,replacement = c("","","",""," - "))
df$cuts <- factor(df$cuts,levels = unique(df$cuts))
df$Gender <- factor(df$Gender,levels = c("Men","Women"))


hist.plot <- function(df)  {ggplot(df,aes(cuts,fill =Gender)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"),alpha=0.8,color="black",width = 0.5) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold",color="#993333", size=8, angle=45,vjust=0.6), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333", size=8, angle=45)) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) 

}
hist.plot(df)
```

[image]

There is no data in `918.8 - 989.9` bin and as you can see I can't show that it has 0 count on the plot

And in `1061 - 1132.1` bin the data belongs to women but appear on the left hand side instead right hand side.

The thing that I should change is about `cut` function or `ggplot` ?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You might try `geom_histogram()`, or `geom_bar()` with `stat = "bin"`, instead of `cut()` + `geom_bar()`.

Comment: You need to delete the line `df$cuts <- factor(df$cuts,levels = unique(df$cuts))` as that will remove unused factor levels from your data structure. And also add `scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)` to your plot code so that unused levels won't be dropped from the plot axis.